# Node MySQL query in loop

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, node-mysql

I am trying to stream real-time stats from a MySQL DB using node JS and MySQL.

I get the datetime of the latest row in each query and in the next query I use this to get rows created after this datetime.

Using the code below, the data contains rows from the last query and keeps increasing in size using data from previous queries.

I'm not sure why?

```js
var authorizeCallback = function(con, socket, shop_id, shopify_domain, last_view, shop_iana_timezone) {
 var sql = "";
 var date, created, loop, rows, data = [], last = last_view;

 socket.emit('connected', 'connected');

 console.log('Connected to shop:', shopify_domain, ' TZ: ', shop_iana_timezone, 'Last view: ' , last_view);
 loop = setInterval(function() {
  var sql = "SELECT * FROM `stats` WHERE `shop_id` = " + con.escape(shop_id) + " AND `created` > '" + last + "' ORDER BY `created` DESC";
  console.log(sql);
  rows = [];
  data = [];
  con.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
   if (err == null && rows[0] && rows[0].shop_id != null) {

    console.log('\n' + 'getting data for: ' + rows.length + ' records ');
    console.log(rows);

    async.each(rows, function(NthRow, done) {
     last = toMySQLDate (rows[0].created);
     date = moment(NthRow.created);
     created = date.tz(shop_iana_timezone).format('hh:mm A');
     row = {
      click : NthRow.click,
      created: created,
      country: geoip.lookupCountry(NthRow.ip),
      mobile : NthRow.mobile,
      title : NthRow.title
     };
     data.push(row);
     async.setImmediate(function() {
      done(null);
     });
    },
    function(err) {
     if (!err) {
      data.reverse();
      socket.emit('message', data);
      console.log('data sent');
     }
    });
   } else {
    console.log('No data');
   }
  });
 }, 2000);
 socket.on('disconnect', function() {
  con.destroy();
  clearInterval(loop);
  console.log(shopify_domain, ' has disconnected');
 });
};
```

Sample Logs:

```
SELECT * FROM `stats` WHERE `shop_id` = 6235393 AND `created` > '2016-

07-12 15:05:35' ORDER BY `created` DESC
getting data for: 2 records 
[ RowDataPacket {
    shop_id: 6235393,
    title: 'Minty Fresh - 2 Week Course',
    created: '2016-07-12 15:05:45',
    mobile: 1,
    click: 0,
   ip: '92.236.109.186' },
 RowDataPacket {
   shop_id: 6235393,
   title: 'Minty Fresh - 4 Week Course',
   created: '2016-07-12 15:05:43',
   mobile: 1,
   click: 0,
   ip: '172.56.15.251' } ]
data sent
SELECT * FROM `stats` WHERE `shop_id` = 6235393 AND `created` > '2016-07-12 15:05:45' ORDER BY `created` DESC
SELECT * FROM `stats` WHERE `shop_id` = 6235393 AND `created` > '2016-07-12 15:05:45' ORDER BY `created` DESC
SELECT * FROM `stats` WHERE `shop_id` = 6235393 AND `created` > '2016-07-12 15:05:45' ORDER BY `created` DESC
SELECT * FROM `stats` WHERE `shop_id` = 6235393 AND `created` > '2016-07-12 15:05:45' ORDER BY `created` DESC
getting data for: 3 records 
[ RowDataPacket {
   shop_id: 6235393,
   title: 'Minty Fresh - 4 Week Course',
   created: '2016-07-12 15:05:53',
   mobile: 1,
   click: 0,
   ip: '86.133.12.239' },
 RowDataPacket {
   shop_id: 6235393,
   title: 'Minty Fresh - 2 Week Course',
   created: '2016-07-12 15:05:45',
   mobile: 1,
   click: 0,
   ip: '92.236.109.186' },
 RowDataPacket {
   shop_id: 6235393,
   title: 'Minty Fresh - 4 Week Course',
   created: '2016-07-12 15:05:43',
   mobile: 1,
   click: 0,
   ip: '172.56.15.251' } ]
data sent
SELECT * FROM `stats` WHERE `shop_id` = 6235393 AND `created` > '2016-07-12 15:05:53' ORDER BY `created` DESC
```

Comment: You'll probably want to investigate using something like [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/) to clean up your database code. It makes writing and executing queries a lot less messy.

Comment: I think the problem here relates to your async function not properly resetting the `data` array. Remember that out-of-order code inside a timer runs at a totally different point in the future, and that it's possible two calls may overlap unless you have some kind of lock.